# Why do I get a Matlab Builder NE exception with supposedly supported toolbox?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have successfully built my series of `.m` script files (including `Pairs.m`) with `deploytool` in the Matlab Builder NE toolbox. I also checked the support setting of the package build to ensure the Econemtric toolbox function I am calling which is `egcitest`.

Everything seems to bridge ok between my C# application and the Builder NE toolbox generated DLL. When it calls `egcitest`, I get a strange exception from the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) which is:

```
.. MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ... 
Error using ==> load 
Unable to read file Data_EGCITest: 
No such file or directory. Error in => Pairs.m at line nn
```

How is this possible if the Matlab Builder NE setting includes the support of `egcitest` from the Econometrics toolbox?

I am using Matlab 2011a and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Is there a file called `Data_EGCITest.*`? Is it in the appropriate directory?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency analysis that the MATLAB Compiler carries out at compile time is unable to pick up the dependency on the data file since it’s not MATLAB code. Any data files that are referenced from code that is being deployed need to be added explicitly to the project.

To do this, add the .mat file to your DEPLOYTOOL project. Drag $MATLABROOT/toolbox/econ/econ/Data_EGCITest.mat into the project where it says “add files/directories” in the Build tab of DEPLOYTOOL.